# WPF: auto resize ListView width according Window size

Tags: wpf, listview, window-resize, autoresize

So i have this `ListView` inside `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Width="70" Height="70" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                 <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                 <ListView>
                     ...    
                 </ListView>
         </Grid>
         <Grid>
         </Grid>
         </Grid>
     </TabItem>
 </TabControl>
```

My window ResizeMode is `CanResizeWithGrip` and when i resize my application i want my `ListView` to auto resize to according my `Window` width.

I try to  define my `ListView` `HorizontalAlignment` `Stretch` bu when my application width changed my `ListView` with not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe since your `ListView` is nested within other controls, those controls would need their `HorizontalAlignment` set to `Stretch`. I'm on my phone right now so I'll try out your XAML on my system when I get home and update my answer if I find something else is the culprit.

Edit: I've copied your code into VS and its stretching properly for me. I don't have any contents to check but if I set

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Width="70" Height="70" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <ListView Background="Black">
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

I can see that the control is in fact stretching when I resize the window. Now I'm unsure of what the issue you are running into is. Any chance you could post more details?